# How to keep the last consecutive line that matches with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, text

I'm trying to match consecutive similar lines in a text file, and only keep the last one. Each line contains a numeric count, so I am matching the text and the digits to get the count.

For example, if I have a lot of consecutive lines with character 'a', I've managed to do it as follows.

```
$ (for i in `seq 1 1 100000`; do echo a; done;) | 
    perl -0777 -pe 's/(a\n)*(a\n)/\2/igs'
a
```

But if I use it with an additional match for digits, perl seems to do it in batches of 2^15.

```
$ (for i in `seq 1 1 100000`; do echo $i; done;) | 
    perl -0777 -pe 's/(\d*\n)*(\d*\n)/\2/igs'
32768
65536
98304
100000
```

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug in perl, or is it documented somewhere? What's the best way to do it?

I am using perl 5.22.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the warnings pragma to your perl script, you get the following information:

```
Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at -e line 1, <> chunk 1.
```

According to [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> **Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (%d) exceeded (W regexp)**
>
> The regular expression engine uses recursion in complex situations
>   where back-tracking is required. Recursion depth is limited to 32766,
>   or perhaps less in architectures where the stack cannot grow
>   arbitrarily. ("Simple" and "medium" situations are handled without
>   recursion and are not subject to a limit.) Try shortening the string
>   under examination; looping in Perl code (e.g. with while ) rather than
>   in the regular expression engine; or rewriting the regular expression
>   so that it is simpler or backtracks less. (See perlfaq2 for
>   information on Mastering Regular Expressions.)

Here's a solution you can use:

```
perl -ne'
   if (/^\d+\n) { $buf = $_; next; }
   print(substr($buf, 0, -1, ""), $_);
   END { print($buf) }
'
```

Comment: Added a solution to the answer.